# javax.persistence.EntityTransaction.commit() take so much time

Tags: java, optimization, entity, commit, jpa

This is a rather vague question, which I apologize for, but I am at the end of the line and have no other place to ask.

I am working with a program that imports data from a *.dat* file and puts it in a database, using the *javax.persistence* library. I have to somehow optimize it since it takes way too much time at the moment (it takes almost 5 seconds to load an 11 KB file). More than 85% of this executing time is in the call to the *commit()* method of the EntityTransaction class.

I have absolutely no idea how one can optimize this since it's a built in java library, and not something I or my colleagues wrote. I found some people talking about [ways to optimize it](http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.se/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html), but I cannot understand how to sue what they are saying.

Does anyone happen to have experience with this, and be willing to led some general advice? Even just a link to an easy-to-understand guide would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You'd need to paste actual code. Are you committing after writing each record?

Comment: I can't, the code belongs to a company so I'm not allowed to post it. It does seem like it imports the whole file at once and calls *commit* only once at the end

Comment: We can't help without the necessary information.

Comment: I understand that helping someone improve some code without getting to see the code is impossible. I'm not asking for a solution, I'm asking to be pointed in the direction of a guide/documentation that can *teach me enough that I can solve it myself* or something like that

Comment: Committing at the end is actually best (in case of too many data, you may want to split).

While 5 seconds for 11 kB is terrible, it may be some slow start up. Try bigger files, try repeating imports. It's quite possible that performance will be fine in the end.
Anyway, for large imports, using SQL or CSV-Imports directly is much more efficient.